# Populate Text Fields from a selected table Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to populate text fields from a table selected first from a `LOV` and user input.

How can I do it in `apex`? How can I manipulate that with processing ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

For small amount of values, I prefer `Select List` item as it looks nice; if there are many values, it can't handle it so I use a `Popup LOV` instead.

In order to populate certain fields with values, you can use a `dynamic action` whose action is `Set value` (and there you can choose *how* to do it; for example, using some PL/SQL code).